# Get Key and values from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am trying to extract Key and values from my JSONObject. But i am not able to do that. Here is the JSON:

```
[{"id":["5"]},{"Tech":["Java"]}]
```

It is a String initially. I have converted that to JSONObject using :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("[{"id":["5"]},{"Tech":["Java"]}]");
```

Then i am trying to get the key and value by:

```
jsonObj.getString("id");
```

But its giving me null. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Your data is a JSON array, not a JSON object.

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON array and you need to perform array / string operations to get `id`.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray("[{\"id\":[\"5\"]},{\"Tech\":[\"Java\"]}]");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        String k = jsonObj.keys().next();
        Log.i("Info", "Key: " + k + ", value: " + jsonObj.getString(k));
    }

} catch (JSONException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The JSON data you show here is not the same as what the OP provided, which was `[{"id":["5"]},{"Tech":["Java"]}]`, note the `},{` in the middle.

Comment: @JasonC Yes I noticed that, So I declare that for him

Comment: The OP is asking how to parse the given JSON data. Suggesting that they use different JSON data does not seem useful.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter you are sending is JsonArray and referring to JsonObject. The Correct way is

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{'id':['5','6']},{'Tech':['Java']}");      
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("id"));

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[{'id':['5','6','7','8']},{'Tech':['Java']}]");
    System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because at `id` you dont have a string , you have a array of string ,

so insted of doing this 
`jsonObj.getString("id");`

do this

`jsonObj.getArray("id");` this will give you that array in return

like if you have a Json Array at `id` then you have to do this

`jsonObj.getJSONArray("id");`

Comment: and yes, remember to add this code in try and catch, because it will throw a unchecked exception

Comment: First, no `JSONObject` implementation that I know of defines a method named `getArray`, second `getJSONArray("id")` would not work for the given JSON data, it would work for `{"id":["5"],"Tech":["Java"]}`, which isn't what was given.

Comment: Hi Vipin. thanks a lot for your response. But it didnt worked out :(. As @JasonC said there is no method getArray when i tried  and getJSONArray("id") is not working.